# How to set value of div textbox (Discord)?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't quite seem to change the value of an element.

Here's the HTML of element 1:

```html
<div data-slate-object="block" data-key="1" style="position: relative;">
```

Element 2 (I think this is the main element):

```html
<div 
    aria-label="Message #channel" 
    aria-multiline="true" 
    data-can-focus="true" 
    data-slate-editor="true" 
    data-key="0" 
    contenteditable="true" 
    class="markup-2BOw-j slateTextArea-1Mkdgw fontSize16Padding-3Wk7zP" 
    autocorrect="off" 
    spellcheck="true" 
    role="textbox" 
    data-gramm="false" 
    style="white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;"
>
```

---

My code (obviously doesn't work):

```js
var tb = document.querySelector('.markup-2BOw-j slateTextArea-1Mkdgw ');

if (tb) {
    var msg = "Hello! This was automatically typed...";
    var int = 7200000;

    function send() {
        tb.innerHTML = msg;

        const ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13 
        });

        document.body.dispatchEvent(ke);
    }

    setInterval(send, int);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for `document.querySelector` needs to be a valid CSS selector. If you replace the whitespace with a `.`, it will select the element correctly.

Here's a demo with the interval set to 3 seconds:

```js
var tb = document.querySelector('.markup-2BOw-j.slateTextArea-1Mkdgw ');

if (tb) {
  var msg = "Hello! This was automatically typed...";
  var int = 3000;

  function send() {
    tb.innerHTML = msg;

    const ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      keyCode: 13
    });

    document.body.dispatchEvent(ke);
  }

  setInterval(send, int);
}
```

```html
<div aria-label="Message #channel" aria-multiline="true" data-can-focus="true" data-slate-editor="true" data-key="0" contenteditable="true" class="markup-2BOw-j slateTextArea-1Mkdgw fontSize16Padding-3Wk7zP" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="true" role="textbox"
  data-gramm="false" style="white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change this line:

```
var tb = document.querySelector('.markup-2BOw-j slateTextArea-1Mkdgw ');
```

to:

```
var tb = document.querySelector('.markup-2BOw-j.slateTextArea-1Mkdgw');
```

You missed a dot. By the way, consider that 7200000 will trigger the event after 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you, fixed. And that was intentional. :) My question still remains though.

Comment: Do you mean that after adding '.', your code still doesn't work?
Does the **element 2** created dynamically? If it is, then you should run your code after the **element 2** has been created.
Could you tell more?

Comment: Yes, and I have it checking if the element exists with an `if` statement.